# How to get the context of a class into an inner static class

Tags: android, static, google-cloud-messaging, inner-classes, android-context

I'm trying to get the context of `FragmentStackSupport` Activity and use it in an inner static class.

I've instantiated `FragmentStackSupport` in the inner static class and I'm using `getBaseContext()` to get the context of `FragmentStackSupport`.

Putting the outer class context inside `GCMRegistar.checkDevice(thisContext)` does not give an error in the code but crashes the application.

I can't use 'this' or `FragmentStackSupport.this` **because the inner class is static**. "this" would work if the class was public ect...

How do I get the context correct for for `checkDevice()` method?

```
public class FragmentStackSupport extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {
    int mStackLevel = 1;
//... 

 public static class CountingFragment extends SherlockFragment  implements OnClickListener{
   //...
FragmentStackSupport FSSContext;

        static CountingFragment newInstance(int num) {

            CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();
            return f;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {


FSSContext= new FragmentStackSupport();
            FSSContext.getBaseContext();
            Context thisContext;
//          
            // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(thisContext);

}
}
}
```

Comment: changing public static with private did not work. It created more errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, However I not sure why it works. But because I'm using sherlock action bar had to use that libaries's specific method

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you're trying to get FSSContext, this should work

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(CountingFragment.this.FSSContext);
```

You can access the surrounding class of an anonymous inner class by using OuterClassName.this (while a simple 'this' refers to the inner class)

**Edit:** Apologies, I missed the main point of this question. According to the documentation for checkDevice, it's intended to take the application context - in your crash example, you're passing it an Activity context (which may be destroyed along with the Activity in question). Use Context.getApplicationContext() instead. Also be aware that checkDevice throws an UnsupportedOperationException if the device doesn't support GCM, so that call should be in a try/catch block.

Comment: `GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(CountingFragment.this.FSSContext);` is crashing the program an I'm getting an  '`: Unable to start activity , NullPointerException ` error. Is there another technique?